# Fetch.js Struggling with result .then syntax

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a fetch statement that has to return an "options" object.

Here is the statement I constructed.

```
   const task = fetch('/api/SelectData/QuerySuburbs' + queryString, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response =>  {options: response}))
```

I know this is incorrect and further I am getting an error on the options name saying its an "unused label"

I would like to return from this an "options" object that contains the returned responses.  How do I construct the syntax so when it returns "task" its like "options: response" ?

Comment: There should be a `(` before `{` in the last line. Did you miss it in this question, or may be that is the issue?

Comment: in an arrow function without {} that needs to return an object, enclose the object in () ... therefore `.then(response =>  ({options: response}))`

Comment: Jaromanda - squgeim - I believe this to be the problem. Syntax error.